# Why are the keys not being deleted from my object?

Tags: javascript-objects

Here is some sample code that is part of an API I am building. The endgame for this part is to simply whittle down objects based on a set of keys passed in via a string array.

```
/**
 * @param {object} vdObj - an array of the raw vendor data
 * @param {Array} keptKeys - an array or strings representing the key names we wish to keep.
 * @returns {object} A 'filtered' object
 */
const objFilter = function objFilter(vdObj, keptKeys) {
  const returnedObjKeys = Object.keys(vdObj);
  const returnedObj = vdObj;

  returnedObjKeys.forEach(key => {
    if (!keptKeys.includes(key)) {
      // If this is not a key that we want to keep...(https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp)
      console.log(key);
      delete returnedObj.key;
    }
  });

  console.log(`returnedObj: ${JSON.stringify(returnedObj)}`);
  return returnedObj;
};

const someObj = {
  fname: "Fatty",
  lname: "McGee",
  age: "29",
  gender: "M"
}

const keptKeys = ["fname", "lname"];

objFilter(someObj, keptKeys);
```

As per: https://jsfiddle.net/visweb/L8xfcdat/1/ `returnedObj` does not seem to have its keys deleted.

Comment: const returnedObj isn't it?

Comment: Well, I just switched to `let` and nothing changed. :(

Comment: It is because console.log(returnedObj.key); prints "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
delete returnedObj[key];
```

instead of

```
delete returnedObj.key;
```

Comment: Yes, I was about to post this answer myself after your comment above!